# How to align Text to right in Text Views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Searched and found many solutions but nothing seems to be working in my case.
I have 2 `TextViews`, side by side.  This is what i am getting in preview.

[image]

***and I want this***

[image]

I have written following code, but its not giving me desired output.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvContactsHeading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="Heading "
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-regular"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvContactsText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="Text "
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-regular"
            />


    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

If i use `android:layout_gravity` to `left` or `right`, it takes the whole text to left or right side.. I want to put both `text in center`, one starts from right corner and other starts from left corner.

Kindly guide me.

Comment: Whats the difference in text alignment on those pictures?

Comment: in 2nd Image, The space between the two images is even, while in the first one, space between the 2 text is uneven.

Comment: @Kirmani88 see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give `match_parent` width to `LinearLayout`.

Use this code.

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvContactsHeading"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="HeadingShort"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-regular"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvContactsText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="TextShort"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-regular"
                />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvContactsHeading2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="HeadingLongggg"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-regular"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvContactsText2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="HeadingLoggg"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-regular"
                />


        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Your Output is

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have checked below XML file by myself ..

just put **android:layout_weight="1"** for both TextView and make  **android:layout_width="0dp"** for both TextView..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-regular"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="this code is working fine for me"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-regular"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="this is right side of the layout"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />


   </LinearLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

hope it will help u :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvContactsHeading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="Heading "
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-regular"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvContactsText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Text "
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-regular"
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add android:layout_weight=1 for each text and then change the gravity as you like

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvContactsHeading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="Heading "
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-regular"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvContactsText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Text "
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-regular"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Also you can do that with relative layout which will be better

Answer (score 1):

Set the `layout_width`to `match_parent`and then apply your desired gravity.
The `LinearLayout`does not allow you to place items on the right. So you have to set the `TextView`to a full width, so you can apply the gravity for it's contents.

The other options is, that you could replace `LinearLayout`with `FrameLayout`.
The `FrameLayout`allows absolute positioning, the `LinearLayout`does not, which would not require to set the `TextView`to a full width.